# Python subprocess returns stderr value, but never stdout?

Tags: python, tcl, stdout

I was trying to automate some work done with scid vs pc chess software. It has commandline version tkscid.exe: https://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/doc/progref.html#game

I called that executable with python's subprocess module.

```
    import subprocess
    
    process = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Scid vs PC-4.21\\bin\\tcscid.exe"],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    
    command = 'sc_base create myfile'
    process.stdin.write(command)
    process.stdin.flush() 

#add more commands
    
    output, error = process.communicate()
    
    print("STDOUT output:")
    print(output)
    
    print("STDERR output:")
    print(error)
```

Obviously, I need some kind of checking after each command, to see that there are no errors, but any attempt to read output or error stream, without closing the exe will crash my code execution.

While trying to fix it, I realized, that I do not actually receive any output ever -  even with communicate.

I have tested each command that I need, by writing them manually on cmd.exe, and they indeed return some output or error message.

Also, my python code works: mistyping any command will result with a message on stderr, and if any command creates file, I can see it being successfully created with file explorer later.

As all similar example tasks are using tcl programming language, I still have no clue, why can't I see the regular exe output or how should I actually catch output with python?

Comment: Are you 100% convinced that the command writes something to stdout?  Has the process completed and closed, so that the buffers are flushed?

Comment: stderr is typically unbuffered, while stdout is fully buffered when writing to a pipe. So you'll see the stderr immediately, but stdout doesn't show up until the buffer fills up or is flushed.

Comment: My commands will print to cmd.exe, when ran manually. I do not know tcl enough to see, whether stdout or some other method is used for that. Also, I do not even try to read anything before process is closed as it would hang my code - as in cannot loop until it sees command prompt sign, but hard stuck on reading line.

Comment: "I have tested each command that I need, by writing them manually on cmd.exe, and they indeed return some output or error message." Did you consider the possibility that everything the command writes is to stderr, so there is nothing for stdout to receive? "I do not know tcl enough to see, whether stdout or some other method is used for that" This has nothing to do with TCL; you need *command-line* skills to determine this. For example, consider using shell redirects.

Comment: I have read the source of used functions: they do not seem to use output functions like 'puts' at all. Instead they append result variable, and return either TCL_OK or TCL_ERROR. Both return types may appear on cmd, but  python's process.communicate duple contains only errors part or nothing.

Comment: Does this work? `process = subprocess.run(["C:\\Scid vs PC-4.21\\bin\\tcscid.exe"], capture_output=True, check=True, text=True, input='sc_base create myfile'); print(process.stdout)`

Answer (score 0):

If the other process (`Scid`) is based on Tcl and hasn't totally restricted what you can do, you should tell it to spit out its output immediately, first, before running any other commands.

```
process.stdin.write("fconfigure stdout -buffering none")
# Or: process.stdin.write("fconfigure stdout -buffering line")
process.stdin.flush()
```

This is important because most processes (both Tcl and Python among them) will fully buffer their output when writing to anywhere that isn't directly the terminal. This is particularly true with pipes. Doing this works *great* when there's a lot of output being produced, giving a really good performance boost (by reducing the number of context switches), but does mean that you don't get everything immediately when the amount of output is small.

If the process doesn't give you a way to switch off output buffering, you'll need to use something like [pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect) to drive the subprocess (which does cunning things with virtual terminals under the covers, so fooling the recalcitrant app into behaving nicely for you). I don't know that package well enough to advise you further, but I'm sure you can ask a follow up question to get help.